# why I cannot recode categories of a variable when using a data file dictionary?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, metaprogramming

I am trying to recode categories within one variable using a file dictionary. And do not understand why it doesn't recode it. Anyone has a solution with the tidyverse library ?

This is my file:

```
 print(app_name_recode_dictionary)
                     content_name             app_name_rename
 1:                DTPbrowser-prod            dtp_browser_prod
 2:        dtp_browser_legacy_code            dtp_browser_prod
 3:                crisprscreenViz           crispr_screen_viz
 4:      crisprscreenviz_orig_code           crispr_screen_viz
 5:    cage_randomiser_legacy_code             cage_randomiser
 6:                 CageRandomizer             cage_randomiser
 7:       moprospector_legacy_code                moprospector
 8:                   moProspector                moprospector
 9: grow_rate_explorer_legacy_code        growth_rate_explorer
10:                Unknown Content        growth_rate_explorer
11:                       ComboCor                   combo_cor
12:           combocor_legacy_code                   combo_cor
13:      Translatability_MultiGene  translatability_multi_gene
14:         multi_gene_legacy_code  translatability_multi_gene
15:              animals_to_groups           animals_to_groups
16:  animals_to_groups_legacy_code           animals_to_groups
17:    Translatability_Single_gene translatability_single_gene
18:        single_gene_legacy_code translatability_single_gene
19:                           FLAT                        flat
20:               flat_legacy_code                        flat
21:          SyngeneicMouseBrowser     syngeneic_mouse_browser
22:    syngeneic_mouse_legacy_code     syngeneic_mouse_browser
23:                      DepMapBem                 dep_map_bem
                          app_name             app_name_rename
```

And this is the code I have tried:

```
factor_recode_app_name <- users_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    app_name =  dplyr::recode_factor(
      content_name,
      !!!app_name_recode_dictionary
    )) %>%
  dplyr::select(-content_name)
```

And got this error:

```
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `app_name`.
ℹ `app_name = dplyr::recode_factor(...)`.
✖ `app_name` must be length 376 or one, not 23.
Caused by error in `glubort()`:
! `app_name` must be length 376 or one, not 23.
```

Comment: You want to `deframe()` the dictionary before splicing it - (e.g. `recode_factor(content_name, !!!deframe(app_name_recode_dictionary))`) as each name/value pair is a separate argument.  Alternatively, use a join.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento - please post this as an answer as it worked super nice!